# Best Practice to Generate PySpark Statements Using C#?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, apache-spark, livy

I am writing a ASP.Net Web API that at some point will communicate with an Apache Spark cluster.

The communication is established using [Livy](https://github.com/cloudera/livy) server on the spark cluster that exposes a REST API interface and an HTTP client i wrote.

In my business logic i need to define operations that will be submitted to spark as jobs.
For now i create a Livy PySpark Session and submit PySpark code.

The PySpark Code is generated by the logic of my Web API.
As an example of code generation, if i want to import a python module i do this :

```
string pythonImportTemplate = "from {0} import {1}";
statements.Add(string.format(pythonImportTemplate, param1, param2));
/*** Post Statements To Spark ***/
```

This seems very wrong and repetitive to me.

My question :  is there any robust way (or design pattern) for generating such code strings minimizing the probability of interpreter (Livy) syntax errors ?